# Vim8 && in :terminal's [command]

Tags: command-line, terminal, bash, shell, vim8

When running the vim command `:!echo A && echo B` the result is as expected

```
A
B

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

However when I try to do the same thing with the new integrated terminal using the command `:term echo A && echo B`, the result is instead

```bash
1 A && echo B
~
~
...
~
~
!echo A && echo B [finished]
```

with the entirety of the rest of the command interpreted as input for the first echo. This also appears for `;` and with other commands. Is there any way to *un*escape the `&&`s, or otherwise add arguments to make the behaviour of `:term` mimic that of `:!`?

Comment: the `&&` is actually a Shell feature and nothing that your echo executes. Therefore, you need to run the command through a shell.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to provide the `++shell` argument to `:terminal`:

```
:term ++shell echo A && echo B
```

This is because `:terminal` tries to execute the entire command as one command, without letting a shell interpret it, unless you tell it to run it through your shell.